# ASP.NET MVC project to port

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dotnetnuke

Is there a project out there that attempts to replicate or re-create a portal framework like DotNetNuke using MVC framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MaVeriCk](http://blog.andrewnurse.net/2009/05/19/MaVeriCkNdashAnOpenSourceCMSWrittenInASPNetMVC.aspx) by Andrew Nurse (son of DNN's Charles Nurse) is a very early attempt at a DNN-like implementation in MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Brad Abrams: http://www.codeplex.com/dropthings

Comment: This is using MVC framework? I think not.

Comment: That was pretty much all I found, so perhaps the answer is "not yet"

Answer (score 0):

[Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) is the only MVC portal (platform) I know of that's somewhat similar to DotNetNuke.

ASP.NET MVC is a bit too new just yet for there to be a wide variety of portal type systems on the market.